# A verb to mean "go to the end of the road"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I would need a transitive verb which would have "road" or "way" or "path" as the direct object. I want to say that a person walks this road to the end in this context:

> This will give them the support and motivation to ______ (meaning *follow to the end*) the path back to safety.

Does such a verb exist? If a single word is not possible, is there a more idiomatic phrase than ***follow/go to the end*** of a road?

Edit 1: I know you can say that you ***traverse a distance***. For example, if you say that you ***traverse the desert***, it means you go from one end to the other end. However, I find it awkward to say ***traverse a road*** to mean ***go all its length***.

I need this verb in other contexts as well. It must mean "to go all the length of".

Edit 2: The French have the term "**parcourir**" which is a transitive verb and means to cover the whole distance of something. But I cannot say "cover a path" in English.

Comment: reach, attain, encompass, gain ... ?

Comment: The path of return to safety? Surely that's the path to danger walked in the opposite direction. "This will give them the support and motivation to *retreat*". "Keep right on to the end of the road"? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbM86eiczAg

Comment: @OldBrixtonian: That's a lot of words before "road"! But thanks, I will keep it in mind.

Comment: To traverse = to go across, not "go along"

Comment: What's wrong with just plain *follow*:   *"This will give them the support and motivation to **follow** the path back to safety."*

Comment: I like @Jim's _follow_. Similar would be to use simply _walk_. These words don't necessarily imply going the full length of the path, but I'm wondering if that's really required. It feels like the "to safety" part of the sentence may already cover that requirement.

Comment: "go the distance" is a common expression, but if you're wanting a single word, thesauruses give nothing better than finish, complete, etc https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/go-the-distance https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/go_the_distance.html

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using "**navigate**" to illustrate completion of an intentional or necessary path to a desired destination.

> This will give them the support and motivation to *navigate* (meaning
> follow to the end) the path of return to safety.

[Oxford Learner's Dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/navigate)

[TFD - navigate](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/navigate)

Answer (score 0):

You could try *negotiate*:

> 4   to move through, around, or over in a satisfactory
> manner:
>  <sub>*to negotiate a difficult dance step without
> tripping: to negotiate sharp curves.*</sub>
>  <sub>Source:
> [Dictionary.com—*negotiate*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/negotiate)</sub>

Like this:

> *This will give them the support and motivation to negotiate the path of return to safety.*